# VB.net - CDate with SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm doing the following query to check if the current month is the same as the SQL field "Start".

```
If Today.Month = CDate(rsData("Start")).Month Then
```

What I'd like to do is switch it so that it will check within a 30 day period rather than identify the current month? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just compare dates with your period boundaries with signs > and <. What trips you up exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Date.Today.AddDays(-30) >= CDate(rsData("Start"))
 ' start date not older than 30 days '
End If
```

or if you have a variable date:

```
var minBoundary = New Date(2011,1,1)
var maxBoundary = New Date(2012,1,1)
var startDate = CDate(rsData("Start"))

If startDate  >= MinBoundary AndAlso startDate <= maxBoundary 
 ' start date between two dates '
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case you would want to use the AddDays method of DateTime.

```
Dim mydate as DateTime = CDate(rsData("Start"))
Dim checkdate as DateTime = mydate.AddDays(30)
```